# Scroll to bottom of div

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to get an automated scroll on click to scroll to the bottom of a div. I have it working but it only scrolls down 600px at a time as thats what i have it set to. Im just not to sure how to get it to scroll directly to the bottom of the div on one click. This is what i have so far. I didnt know if there was an easier way of writing the jquery code I have done so far as well.

```js
 $('.scroll-down').on('click', function() {
   var currentScrollPosition = 0;
   currentScrollPosition += 600;
   $('.bx-viewport').animate({
     scrollTop: currentScrollPosition
   }, 2000);
 });
 $('.scroll-up').on('click', function() {
   var currentScrollPosition = 0;
   currentScrollPosition -= 600;
   $('.bx-viewport').animate({
     scrollTop: currentScrollPosition
   }, 2000);
 });
```

```css
.bx-viewport {
  height: 600px !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative
}
.scroll-up {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.scroll-down {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
img {
  height: 900px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bx-viewport">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x1000" />
</div>
<div class="scroll-down">scroll down</div>
<div class="scroll-up">scroll up</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `scrollHeight` property and subtract the height of the element to find the available space to scroll.

```js
$('.scroll-down').on('click', function() {
   var target = $('.bx-viewport'),
       height = target.height(),
       scrollHeight = target.prop('scrollHeight');
  
   target.animate({
     scrollTop: scrollHeight-height
   }, 2000);
 });

 $('.scroll-up').on('click', function() {
   $('.bx-viewport').animate({
     scrollTop: 0
   }, 2000);
 });
```

```css
.bx-viewport {
  height: 600px !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative
}
.scroll-up {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.scroll-down {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
img {
  height: 900px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bx-viewport">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x1000" />
</div>
<div class="scroll-down">scroll down</div>
<div class="scroll-up">scroll up</div>
```